# Нужно подсчитать сколько раз каждое слово встречается в тексте. Некоторые (меньшая часть) слова подсчитываются неверно. Почему?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, java-stream

Я изучаю стримы, задание - написать метод, который возвращает строку, отображающую все встречающиеся в тексте слова и их количество.

Вот код, который я написал:

```
public class Words {


StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public String toStroka(Map<String, Integer> map) {

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {

        String s = entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue();
        sb.append(s).append("\n");
    }

    return sb.toString().trim();

}



public String countWords(List<String> lines) {

    //убираем в каждой строке все кроме пробелов и букв и понижаем регистр
    List<String> list = lines.stream().
            map(line -> line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё ]", "").toLowerCase()).
            collect(Collectors.toList());


    //делаем из листа строку
    String s = list.toString();

    //сплитим ее по пробелам
    String[] arr = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё ]+", "").split(" ");

    Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(arr).
            filter(word -> word.length()>=4).
            collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, val -> 1, Integer::sum));


    Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream().sorted((e1,e2) ->{

        int comp = e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
        if (comp != 0) {
            return -comp;
        } else {
            return e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
        }


    } ).
            filter(e -> e.getValue()>=10).
            collect(LinkedHashMap::new,

                    (m, c) -> m.put(c.getKey(), c.getValue()),

                    LinkedHashMap::putAll);


    return toStroka(sortedMap);
} }
```

Вот пример того, что получается в результате применения метода к тексту "Войны и мира". Несколько самых часто встречающихся слов:

Что должно получиться:

было - 2519
сказал - 2016
только - 1621
пьер - 1401
князь - 1354
когда - 1145
чтобы - 998
того - 924

Что получается:

было - 2519
сказал - 2016
только - 1620
пьер - 1401
князь - 1354
когда - 1145
чтобы - 997
того - 924

Большинство слов подсчитывается верно, но часть - нет. В приведенном примере неверно подсчитаны слова "только" и "чтобы". "Только" должно встречается 1621 раз, а выводится, что 1620, "чтобы" повторяется в тексте 998 раз, а пишет, что 997.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Если исключить опечатки в заданных словах (например вместо кирилличных `'о'` стоят буквы из латиницы `'o'`), то вероятно, что в процессе удаления небуквенных и непробельных символов из исходного текста некоторые слова могли быть склеены со своими соседями, и соответственно они были отфильтрованы по условию `filter(e -> e.getValue()>=10)`.  Для проверки этой гипотезы следует посчитать частоту подозрительных слов, используя `String::contains`:

```java
long countOnly = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .filter(w -> w.contains("только"))
    // отладка: вывести слова, не равные "только"
    .peek(w -> {if (!w.equals("только")) System.out.println("Не 'только': " + w);})
    .count();
```

Если это предположение подтвердится, то необходимо исправить подход к очистке  строки от ненужных символов.  Также следует отметить, что в тексте "Войны и мира" достаточно часто попадаются французские слова, в котором много символов с диакритическими знаками, которые также некорректно удаляются.  Поэтому следует использовать другие классы символов для фильтрации допустимых символов, например, [`\p{L}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) - любая буква на любом языке, `\p{Z}` - любой пробельный символ, соответственно, `\P{L}` - любой небуквенный символ, по *последовательности* которых `\P{L}+` можно *сразу* разбивать входные строки:

```java
public Map<String, Integer> wordMap(List<String> lines) {

    return lines.stream()
        .map(line -> line.toLowerCase().split("\\P{L}+")) // Stream<String[]>
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream) // Stream<String>
        .filter(word -> word.length() > 3)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            word -> word, // или Function.identity()
            Collectors.summingInt(word -> 1)
        )) // таблица частот всех слов
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 9)
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
            .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            (f1, f2) -> f1,
            LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
}

// тест
System.out.println(toStroka(wordMap(lines)));
```