# Как можно оптимизировать (используя лямбда-выражения или stream API) код ниже изложенный, имея следующие условия задания?

Tags: java, оптимизация, map, java-stream, lambda

*Реализовать метод, который принимает путь к файлу.
Метод возвращает частоту повторяемости всех слов в тексте в порядке возрастания частоты повторяемости.*

```
public Map<String, Integer> getCountOfWordsCharFrequency(String way) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> list = getListStringFromFile(way);

    Integer value;

    for (String stringOfWord : list) {
        String[] text = stringOfWord.split(" ");
        for (String word : text) {
            value = map.get(word);
            if (value == null) {
                map.put(word.toLowerCase(), 1);
            } else {
                map.put(word.toLowerCase(), value + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .collect(Collectors
                    .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно использовать поток строк, который возвращается при помощи `Files.lines` вместо вызова некоего метода `getListStringFromFile`,возвращающего коллекцию (список) строк.

Также понадобится применить `Stream::flatMap` после применения `String.split`, как примерно [показано здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1347836/386633):

```java
public Map<String, Integer> getWordFrequencies(String path) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
        return input
            .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\\P{L}+"))) // поток слов
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                word -> word,
                Collectors.summingInt(word -> 1)
            )) // Map<String, Integer>
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (v1, v2) -> v1,
                LinkedHashMap::new
            ));
    }
}
```

В [данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1375824/386633) на вопрос [Нужно подсчитать сколько раз каждое слово встречается в тексте. Некоторые (меньшая часть) слова подсчитываются неверно.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1375681/386633) показан пример более точного разбиения на слова при помощи регулярного выражения `\P{L}+`, а также дополнительной фильтрации слов по длине и частоте вхождения, и улучшенной сортировки слов по *убыванию частоты* и в алфавитном порядке при совпадении частот.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь